# Aligning divs between two divs

Tags: html, css

**aligning divs between two divs**

The two divs in between are not properly aligned with the two red divs on both sides.
I used “.menu:nth-child(2n){margin-top:-20px;}” as Monika suggested but still cannot get the result

[image]

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu {
height:200px;
width: 25%;
float:left;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid red;
background:red;
}
.men {
height:200px;
width: 25%;
float:left;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid red;
background:green;
margin-top:-20px;
}
.main {margin-top:5%;
height:20px;
width: 50%;
float:left;
padding:0px;
border: 1px solid red;
background:#222;
}
.mai {
margin-top:5%;
height:30px;
width: 50%;
float:left;
padding:0px;
border: 1px solid red;
background:#222;}  
<div class="menu"><ul><li>The Flight</li> </ul></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="mai"></div>
<div class="men"><ul> P<li>The Flight</li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Please write you HTML structure, it will be easy to suggest

Comment: Please post your HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[screenshot after removing the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVETt.png)

According to your code, they're not aligning because you have a `margin-top` for `.main`, just remove the line.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu {
height:200px;
width: 25%;
float:left;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid red;
background:red;
}
.men {
height:200px;
width: 25%;
float:left;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid red;
background:green;
margin-top:-20px;
}
.main {
height:20px;
width: 50%;
float:left;
padding:0px;
border: 1px solid red;
background:#222;
}
.mai {
margin-top:5%;
height:30px;
width: 50%;
float:left;
padding:0px;
border: 1px solid red;
background:#222;}
```

```html
<div class="menu"><ul><li>The Flight</li> </ul></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="mai"></div>
<div class="men"><ul> P<li>The Flight</li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved by using pseudo class, please check the css below

```
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 
.menu {
  height:200px;
  width: 25%;
  float:left; 
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
 background:red;
}
.menu:nth-child(2n){
  margin-top:-20px;
}
.main {
  height:20px;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid red; 
  background:#222;
}
.mai {
  margin-top:5%;
  height:30px;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  padding:0px; 
  border: 1px solid red; 
  background:#222;
}`
```